# jQuery validate plugin : custom rules with dynamic element id

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have attempted to apply a custom validation rule using jQuery as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notaccept", function(value, element, param) {
return value.match(new RegExp("." + param + "$"));
}, "<img src='../template/images/error.gif' alt='Only alphabet allowed.'>");

$("#frm1").validate({
  rules: {
    $('input[id^=txt_field]'): { 
        notaccept: "[a-zA-Z]+" }        
  }
});
});
</script>
```

The issue is the usage of element prefix selector in the above code doesn't work. I generate multiple field of the format `txt_field11`, `txt_field12` and so on dynamically.

Can I apply the above validation on multiple elements as in my case?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the `rules` option is powerful enough to accept an arbitrary selector for elements and apply a validation rule for those elements.

You can, however, add rules after initializing validator:

```
$.validator.addMethod("notaccept", function(value, element, param) {
    return value.match(new RegExp("^" + param + "$"));
}, "Only alphabet allowed");

$("#form").validate({...});

$('input[id^="txt_field"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", { notaccept: "[a-zA-Z]+" });
});
```

The `.each` call was necessary because it looked like validator was only calling `.rules()` on the first matched item.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/fDAQU/

I'll do some more digging and see if there's a way to add rules in the options object you initially pass to validator.