# using ID selector for to addMethod for jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to add a validation rule for jQuery validate

```
$validator.addMethod('footer-email', function (value) {
  if (value == ''){
    return true;
  }
}, '');
```

Where `footer-email` is class selector. Is there a way I can use a ID selector instead?

Comment: First parameter inside `.addMethod()` is the "name" of this new rule, NOT a class, although you can use the name of the rule as a class to declare the rule on a field.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs, it looks like the first parameter is the name of validation method you are adding, not the element selector. You would later use

```
$validator.addMethod('valid_email', function(value) { ... });
$('#my_form').validate({
    rules: {
        my_field: {
            valid_email: true
        }
    }
})
```

I don't think it's powerful enough to support custom selectors. See related question: [jQuery validate plugin : custom rules with dynamic element id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716476/jquery-validate-plugin-custom-rules-with-dynamic-element-id)
.